# Pregunta sobre clase de usuarios

Tags: php, cuenta-usuario

Tengo este codigo pero no se como modificarlo para poder manejar diferentes clases de usuario con privilejios y otros no es un inventario pero que estoy adaptandolo para poder manejarlo como help desk tambien bn dejo el login.php alguna pregunta me avisan pls gracias

```
    <?php

    /**
 * Class login
 * handles the user's login and logout process
*/
class Login
{
/**
 * @var object The database connection
 */
private $db_connection = null;
/**
 * @var array Collection of error messages
 */
public $errors = array();
/**
 * @var array Collection of success / neutral messages
 */
public $messages = array();

/**
 * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
 * you know, when you do "$login = new Login();"
 */
public function __construct()
{
    // create/read session, absolutely necessary
    session_start();

    // check the possible login actions:
    // if user tried to log out (happen when user clicks logout button)
    if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
        $this->doLogout();
    }
    // login via post data (if user just submitted a login form)
    elseif (isset($_POST["login"])) {
        $this->dologinWithPostData();
    }
}

/**
 * log in with post data
 */
private function dologinWithPostData()
{
    // check login form contents
    if (empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Username field was empty.";
    } elseif (empty($_POST['user_password'])) {
        $this->errors[] = "Password field was empty.";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_password'])) {

        // create a database connection, using the constants from config/db.php (which we loaded in index.php)
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        // change character set to utf8 and check it
        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
            $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }

        // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

            // escape the POST stuff
            $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

            // database query, getting all the info of the selected user (allows login via email address in the
            // username field)
            $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, firstname, user_email, user_password_hash
                    FROM users
                    WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_name . "';";
            $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

            // if this user exists
            if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

                // get result row (as an object)
                $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();

                // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
                // the hash of that user's password
                if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                    // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
                    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $result_row->firstname;
                    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                    $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "Problema de conexión de base de datos.";
        }
    }
}

/**
 * perform the logout
 */
public function doLogout()
{
    // delete the session of the user
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    // return a little feeedback message
    $this->messages[] = "Has sido desconectado.";

}

/**
 * simply return the current state of the user's login
 * @return boolean user's login status
 */
public function isUserLoggedIn()
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    // default return
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar la DB y agregar un campo user_permision cuando realizas la consulta de login agregas a los datos que grabas en $_SESSION el user_permision.

```
$_SESSION['user_permision'] = $result_row->user_permision;
```

Saludos.

Comment: y como lo puedo probar perdon por la boba pregunta pero estoy muy estresado para pensar con claridad

Comment: Hola Kevin, cuando ingresas al sistema almacenas los datos, que posteriormente vas a utilizar, en variables de sesión. Si la entrada fue exitosa en las partes que necesites del código deberas preguntar if($_SESSION['user_permision'] == 1){ haga Algo;} else{haga otra cosa;}. Solo veo código de login en la pregunta, si hay mas código debería editar la pregunta y marcar bien el código.

Comment: muchas gracias si ya se que esta validando pero ahora mi pregunta con el if se podria hacer una validacion que permita la autenticacion de usuarios en plan, usuario, administrador, tecnico etc gracias

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta. En esa clase no le conviene mezclar código solo agregue el valor que necesita, (siempre hablando por como veo que esta hecho el código). Esa clase tiene una única responsabilidad. En la pagina que llama a la clase **login** debería direccionar de acuerdo al perfil cargado en la DB. Por ejemplo anidando **if** para limitar o no las vistas.

Comment: osea no se como editar el login para que queden diferentes roles de acuerdo a donde esten asignados

Comment: Es que el login no ejecuta ninguna acción mas que guardar los valores en sesión.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {

        // escape the POST stuff
        $user_name = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);

        // database query, getting all the info of the selected user (allows login via email address in the
        // username field)
        $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, firstname, user_email, user_password_hash, user_permision
                FROM users
                WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "' OR user_email = '" . $user_name . "';";
        $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);

        // if this user exists
        if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {

            // get result row (as an object)
            $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();

            // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
            // the hash of that user's password
            if (password_verify($_POST['user_password'], $result_row->user_password_hash)) {

                // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $result_row->firstname;
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
                $_SESSION['user_permision'] = $result_row->user_permision;
                $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;

            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
            }
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = "Usuario y/o contraseña no coinciden.";
        }
    } else {
        $this->errors[] = "Problema de conexión de base de datos.";
    }
```

Ahí agregue las variables, pero en la DB debe agregar el campo **user_permision** con valores para cada rol de usuario. Por ejemplo: Para  plan = 1, usuario = 2, administrador = 3, tecnico = 4.
Luego tendra que redireccionar u ocultar partes de acuerdo a estos valores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si son dos usuarios administrador y usuario solo agrego esoso? que pena con la pregunta tan tonta pero es para saber y aprender bien

Comment: tengo que agragar otro campo a la base de datos o a dentro de la tabla usuairios

Comment: Exacto, a la tabla **users**

Comment: ya lo agregue pero no se como integrarlo para que el sistema lo reconozca

Comment: ya lo hice solo con meter un if ya muchas gracias